# How to limit fields that map in @RequestBody

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I'm trying to implement a very basic Spring Boot web application. In that I map a JSON object to an entity (says Customer Entity) with the help of `@RequestBody`.

In **addCustomer** method, I want to bind/map only the *firstName* & *lastName* fields and ignore *Id* field even if the client response JSON has that field.

And in **updateCustomer** method I need to map all the fields including *Id* because I need *Id* field to update the entity.

How can I ignore some or one field in auto-mapping process of the `@RequestBody`.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer-service")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerServiceImpl customerService; 

    //This method has to ignore "id" field in mapping to newCustomer
    @PostMapping(path = "/addCustomer")
    public void addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer) {
        customerService.saveCustomer(newCustomer);
    }

    //This method has to include "id" field as well to updatedCustomer
    @PostMapping(path = "/updateCustomer")
    public void updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer updatedCustomer) {
        customerService.updateCustomer(updatedCustomer);
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long cusId;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //Default Constructor and getter-setter methods after here
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple `@JsonView`s to use different mappings in each method.

1. Define views:

```java
public class Views {
    public static class Create {
    }
}
```

2. Select which fields should be used in each view:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long cusId;

    @JsonView(Views.Create.class)
    private String firstName;
    @JsonView(Views.Create.class)
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

3. Tell Spring MVC to use this view in particular method:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/addCustomer")
public void addCustomer(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.Create.class) Customer newCustomer) {
    customerService.saveCustomer(newCustomer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem of ignoring "Id" field even if user provides it in the "addCustomer()" method. But is there a way to make "updateCustomer()" method to throw exception if the "Id" field is null? because code I have now maps the "Id" field null if the user doesn't provide it. Or Is it better to check the content of the "Id" within the "updateCustomer()" and handle it manually within the method?

Comment: You can use validation groups from JSR 303 `@NotNull(group = ...)`, but it gets already quite complex with json views and validation groups. Perhaps you can consider having separate objects you bind request body to and then map them to customer. It means a bit of duplication but I think code will be simpler to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Use one of the following:

- `@JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname")` on your class.
- `@JsonIgnore` on your field to ignore its mapping.

Example:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties("custId")
public class Customer {

@JsonIgnore
private String custId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

BUT, as you've the same POJO, it will skip "custId" mapping for both the requests.

AFAIK, you should not be receiving `custId` value for your `@PostMapping` (adding customer) so it'll be dynamically set to null or default value. And while creating a user, you should also create ID for it or let database take care of it.

And for `@PutMapping` (updating user) you must be getting the ID value which can be used to identify user and then make an update.

Comment: if JsonIgnore ignores the field in both methods that solution may not be the exact match. Yes, exactly as you said, in "AddingCustomer"  method I want to ignore the "Id" since it's created by hibernate. and in "updatingCustomer" method I need the "Id" field to be mapped because I need it to do the update.